# How to parse URL's simultaneously in constructor?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, jsoup

I have a class called "Parser" that can be used to get a price from a url and parse it into an integer.

I then have other classes which uses those variables to create objects. Problem is that because it is running serially it is very slow.

How do I get them to parse the URL's in parallel?

```
public class Parser {
    public static int getPrice(String url) {
        String price = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            price = doc.select("h3").select("span").attr("title");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parseInt(price);
    }

    public static double parseDouble(String parseMe) {
        NumberFormat ukFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK);
        double parsed = 0;
        try {
            parsed = ukFormat.parse(parseMe).doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parsed;
    }
}

//Here is an example of the class
public class Example(){
    private int field1, field2;

    public Example(String url1, String url2){
        field1=Parser.getPrice(url1);
        field2=Parser.getPrice(url2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like the `getPrice` calls to run asynchronously, you can use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), like so:

```
public Example(String url1, String url2) {
    // Create executorService.
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    // Submit both tasks to executorService.
    Future<Integer> future1 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return Parser.getPrice(url1);
        }
    });
    Future<Integer> future2 = executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return Parser.getPrice(url2);
        }
    });

    // Shutdown executorService. (It will no longer accept tasks, but will complete the ones in progress.)
    executorService.shutdown();

    // Handle results of the tasks.
    try {
        // Note: get() will block until the task is complete
        field1 = future1.get();
        field2 = future2.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Handle it
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Handle it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same case, for me I had to had them to parse the two URL in the same function , and instead of returning an Integer, it returns instead an array of two integers, and it was more fast.
in your case I would suggest working with [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) in a way that your code would look like:

```
final CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(2); // the parameter 2 is the number of threads that will invode the await method

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();// this is just the start time to measure how many it took
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                cb.await();
                int field1 = Parser.getPrice(url1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }};

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    cb.await();
                    int field2 = Parser.getPrice(url2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }};

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();// end time of execution
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(duration);
```